# Why does my program return garbage when accessing the value of a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

When the below code is run, I get garbage output. I have debugged it enough to figure out the error comes when I try to access `hobbies[i]->hobby`. Any help would be appreciated. I have been trying to figure out what is going on for hours.

```
int Graph::addUserToHobby(std::string hobby, std::string id){
  int key = ((int)hobby[0] + (int)hobby[1])%HASHMAP_SIZE;
  int collisions = 0;
  while(hobbies[key] != NULL && hobbies[key]->hobby.compare(hobby) != 0 ){
    key++;
    collisions++;
    if(key >= HASHMAP_SIZE){
      key = 0;
    }
  }

  if(hobbies[key] == NULL){
    hobbylist hob;
    hob.hobby = hobby;
    hob.list.push_back(findVertex(id));
    hobbies[key] = &hob;
  }
  else{
    hobbies[key]->list.push_back(findVertex(id));
  }
  return collisions;

}

void Graph::displayHobbies(){

  for(int i=0; i<HASHMAP_SIZE; i++){
    if(hobbies[i] != NULL){
      cout << hobbies[i]->hobby << ": ";
      for(unsigned int j=0; j<hobbies[i]->list.size()-1; j++){
        cout << hobbies[i]->list[j]->name << ", ";
      }
      cout <<  hobbies[i]->list[hobbies[i]->list.size()-1]->name << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you hoping `hobbies[key] = &hob` does?

Comment: hobbies[] is an array of pointers. I want to put hob in that array as a pointer.

Comment: Assuming you have `Hobby *hobbies[HASHMAP_SIZE];` somewhere, replace it with `std::map<std::string, Hobby> hobbies;` and everything will become much simpler.

Comment: Why `hobbies` contain pointers and not the `hobbylist` objects themselves? If you insist on pointers (which implies additional memory and runtime overhead), consider using smart ones, such as `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @DanielLangr Wouldn't `std::shared_ptr` be a better choice here?

Comment: you are not accessing the value of the pointer, but you are dereferencing the pointer to access the value of the pointee.

Comment: @KenY-N Why? I don't see any reason for `std::shared_ptr`, which has much higher memory/runtime overhead with reference counting and type-erased deleters. But we don't see all the program code.

Comment: To the close-voter: I am pretty sure the problem was not a typo.

Answer (score 9):

Focus your attention in that part of the code:

```
if(hobbies[key] == NULL) {
  hobbylist hob;
  ...        
  hobbies[key] = &hob;
}
```

When `hob` gets out of scope (at the end of that if-statement's body), `hobbies[key]` will reference something that doesn't exist any more.

Later on in your program, as you correctly noticed, when you do `cout << hobbies[i]->hobby;`, you will request for `hobby` on something that has gone out of scope, which invokes *Undefined Behavior* (UB).

---

Some possible solutions:

1. Use an [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/), instead of the array of pointers you use
   now. The container will automatically take care of the memory
   management for you. (Recommended)
2. Use smart pointers (e.g. [`std::unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/)), instead of raw pointers. Read more in
   [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)
3. Dynamically allocate `hob`, so that its lifetime is extended (that
   means that when that if-statement's body terminates, `hob`'s
   lifetime won't terminate). This approach requires *you* to be
   responsible for the memory management (you have to de-allocate every
   piece of memory that you dynamically allocated before (call `delete`
   as many times as you called `new`)).

Comment: This is why vectors or other containers are preferred to than `C` style arrays!

Comment: @FrancisCugler improved my answer, thanks to your comment!

Answer (score 2):

In this part:

```
if(hobbies[key] == NULL){
  hobbylist hob;
  /* ... */
  hobbies[key] = &hob;
}
```

`hob` is allocated on the stack and deleted after the if block. So the pointer you have in `hobbies[key]` is dangling. You can catch these sort of errors with valgrind.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are populating your `hobbies` value with pointers to objects **allocated on the stack**.

These objects will have subsequently been destroyed.  Perhaps you were meaning to allocate them on the heap with `new`?

```
hobbylist* hob = new hobbylist;
...
hobbies[key] = hob
```